# Disable part of the script when using mouse

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using the 3 finger drag script and another script in the same ahk, the problem is when I'm connected to a mouse at home, I can't use the mouse to drag the file as long as this script is running. I want only the 3 finger drag part of the script is disabled during the period of time that my mouse is connected. Thanks!

My script as follow:

#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

--zoom with page up and down
PgUp:: Send, {CTRLDOWN}{+}
PgDn:: Send, {CTRLDOWN}{-}

--3 finger drag
#SingleInstance force

drag_enabled := 0

+^#F22::
if(drag_enabled)
{
Click up
drag_enabled := 0
}
else
{
drag_enabled := 1
Click down
}
return

LButton::
if(drag_enabled)
{
Click up
drag_enabled := 0
}
else
click
return

Answer (score 0):

You can check the active status of hotkeys with "#if expression".

[Examine the #if statement:](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#Basic_Operation)

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\mouhid\Enum" in "Count"
When the count is 0, it means that there is no mouse attached to the system.

```
MouseCnt(){ ;Retrieves mouse status data from the registry.
RegRead,MouseC,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\mouhid\Enum,Count
return MouseC
}
    
#if !MouseCnt() ;When the exclamation point is removed, your shortcuts within this expression will only work when the mouse is attached.
/*
Your hotkeys that will work when the mouse is unpluged.
*/
#if
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand where should I put my 3 finger drag script to make it work.